# How to Pop to a View Controller without Animation

Tags: ios, iphone, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller, poptoviewcontroller

I would like to display an image in response to a local notification event that occurs while the iPhone is locked. When the user swipes on the notification, I would like my app to go to the root view controller, via popToViewController:animated, and then push a view controller that displays the image. This works when I set animated = YES. When animated = NO, the view controller that displays the image doesn't respond when the user taps the back button. Any thoughts on why the image view controller's navigation controls don't work when I popToViewController without animation? Thanks in advance.

Here's the relevant code...

```
- (void) localNotificationHandler
{
#ifdef kAnimatePop
    animated = YES;    // This works
#else
    animated = NO;     // This doesn't work
#endif
    _showImage = YES;

    // Check if this view controller is not visible
    if (self.navigationController.visibleViewController != self) {
        // Check if there are view controllers on the stack
        if ([self.navigationController.viewControllers count] > 1) {
            // Make this view controller visible
            [self.navigationController popToViewController:self animated:animated];
        }
    }
}    


- (void) viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
    if (_showImage) {
        _showImage = NO;
        // Show image in a view controller
        [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"MainToImageSegue" sender:self];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't set _showImage until after popToViewController has been invoked.  If it's animated viewDidAppear won't be called until later, so it unexpectedly works.  If it's not animated then viewDidAppear is called immediately, before _showImage has been set.  Move `_showImage = true;` to before the nav controller stack manipulations.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but that's not causing the issue. I'll edit my code to avoid confusion.

Answer (score 0):

I might do the check this way:

```
- (void) localNotificationHandler{
...

...
    if (self.navigationController.topViewController != self) {
        [self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:NO];
    }
}
```

I would also recommend pushing your image view controller programmatically with something like

```
[self.navigationController pushViewController:<imageVC> animated:YES];
```

If your image view controller's navigation buttons are not working, it is likely because it is sending those navigation messages to `nil`. aka, the imageViewControllers `self.navigationController` is equal to `nil`. 
I'm not sure how to fix this with storyboards, but if you present it programatically that problem should go away.

Comment: The root VC can be the topViewController but not be visible, if a modal VC is being displayed. I'm not sure if there is a difference between manually pushing the VC and using the segue method. BTW, the navigationController is not nil. Thanks for the answer.